# Trying to put lightbox preloader in center

Tags: css

On the following site: http://vv.dev.ikonami.com/ when I click on "support" in the footer the preloader spinner is not centered. Below is the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove in-line style `height:445px;width:575px` and update following

```
#modal-content
{
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-top:22px;
}
```

and adjust any minor changes according your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

add folowing css to your existing css

```
.modal-content{
padding-left: 0px;
}

/*or else just delete that line says "Padding-left: 92px;"*/
```

and add `margin-left 92px;` to a form